# Exception while property mapping at property path "image": The identity property "download.png" is no UID in typo3

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-11.x

Created additional image field in one extension created using extension builder.
Followed step mentioned in typo3 document(Modern extension development with extbase and fluid).
When i tried to update and add image field i am getting error.

(1/2) #1297759968 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception
Exception while property mapping at property path "image": The identity property "download.png" is no UID.

I would like to remove this errror

Comment: Sound a bit like file handling *before* FAL. Which edition of the book are you reading? The 1st version was published 2010. At this time, TYPO3 4.5 was the current version. With v6, the File Abstraction Layer (FAL) has been introduced and the handling of files has changed very much.
The current way of handling files is documented e.g. in https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/Tca.html

Comment: Where do you "update and add"? In the Backend? If yes, please copy the relevant field from TCA.

Comment: 3rd addition of Typo3v9 LTS

Comment: (1/2) #1297759968 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception
Exception while property mapping at property path "image": The identity property "download.png" is no UID.

Comment: Solved my issue its because i forgot to add enctype="multipart/form-data" In form